# Self-deleted posts and the 3 vote / 60 day rule

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

With regards to [Shog's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) post about [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) and the part about retaining reputation earned from deleted posts that have a score of 3 or better and were visible on the site for 60 days, does this also apply to *self-deleted* posts and will it continue to do so?

I culled a few of my own answers over the weekend that were less than stellar, and my reputation dropped 1.8k, but the rep is back today after the changes were announced.

I thought it would be useful to clarify that this also applies to self-deleted stuff.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<strike>I obviously can't provide an official response, but</strike> the way I read the blog post, yes, this *does* apply to self-deleted posts.

Note the following paragraph under the first point (emphasis added):

> In fast-changing professions, there should be no shame in contributing valuable information just because it eventually goes out of date – and there shouldn’t be a penalty for deleting it when it does. Naturally, editing to bring an answer up-to-date is preferable – but if someone else already posted a good answer with current information, **you should be able to remove yours and keep the reward for the time it was useful**.

Comment: This is the answer. And this is *specifically* the reason why I was Ok with this (fairly drastic) change to how reputation works.