# What does "full reputation history" provide in addition to "reputation history"?

Tags: support, reputation, api

There is an [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history) for "full reputation history", in addition to [one](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-reputation-history) for just "reputation history". What does the "full" version give me that's missing in the regular one? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *reputation history* API shows a user's public reputation changes. The *full reputation history* requires an access token and shows things like deleted posts which are not public.

From the [docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), it says that *reputation history* does not get private events:

> Get a history of a user's reputation, excluding private events.

For info on private events see:

- [What are private reputation events?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294552/707129)

Comment: What are "private" events?

Comment: @BellmanEqn see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294552/295232